# corresponds to your mariadb server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com'

Tags: c#, mysql

ok i have searched everywhere and all the things i find are not exactly what i'm looking for or i'm to DANG tired to see it.
I'm trying to do a search on EMAIL to see if a customer is in my database or not. IF the customer is in my database i want to fill all the textboxs so they don't have to reenter the information.

MySQL, C#, Visual Studio 2017 Community, Windows FORM Program.

here is my code that keeps giving me this error:
corresponds to your mariadb server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com'

THANK YOU for any input from advanced users.

```
                if (r)
            {

                dbconn();
                string SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM integercorp_TechIT.users WHERE Email="+ tb_Email.Text;
                Command = new MySqlCommand(SelectQuery, connect);
                MDR = Command.ExecuteReader();
                if (MDR.Read())
                {
                    tb_LastName.Text = MDR.GetString("Last");
                    tb_FirstName.Text = MDR.GetString("First");
                    tb_Address1.Text = MDR.GetString("Address1");
                    tb_Address2.Text = MDR.GetString("Address2");
                    tb_PhoneNo.Text = MDR.GetString("Phone");
                    tb_CellNo.Text = MDR.GetString("Cell");
                    tb_City.Text = MDR.GetString("City");
                    tb_County.Text = MDR.GetString("County");
                    tb_Email2.Text = MDR.GetString("Email");
                    tb_State.Text = MDR.GetString("State");
                    tb_ZipCode.Text = MDR.GetString("ZipCode");
                    btn_NextCustInfo.Focus();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome new Customer!!!!");

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with your concatenated query, The column `Email` will accept a string value. which means the value should be within pair od single quotes in case of concatenated query. But that would not be a better solution here you have to go for parameterization. in that case you can form the query like the following:

```
string SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM integercorp_TechIT.users WHERE Email=@mail";
Command = new MySqlCommand(SelectQuery, connect);
Command.Parameters.Add("@mail", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = tb_Email.Text;
// Proceed with your codes
```

Comment: this actually performs faster for some reason beyond my comprehension at the very tired moment. Thank you !!!!!!!!

Comment: @RickCrowell : You can mark it as accepted if my suggestions really help you to solve the issues

Comment: the only thing i had to change in your suggested code was the SqlDbType to MySqlDbType.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM integercorp_TechIT.users WHERE Email='"+ tb_Email.Text+"'";
```

For email value of textbox to be recognized as string put it in single quote.

Comment: HOLY BLONDE MOMENT BATMAN. DOUGHT!!!! thank you so much for the fix. I think i'm going home to bed now. hahahahha.

Answer (score 0):

```
string SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM integercorp_TechIT.users WHERE Email='"+ tb_Email.Text+"'";
```

just put single quote before and after Email id. Because Email accept string value

Comment: Hope that you are aware about SQLInjection, then why are you opening a wide door for hackers through this concatenated query?

Comment: @un-lucky I only correct the error which he is getting in the code. I am not giving him any suggestion.